# Can't access CouchDB remotely

Tags: couchdb

I have changed the `bind_address` to `0.0.0.0`.

`netstat -an | grep 5984` yields the following:

`tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5984            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN`

From what I've about this, everything seems to be in order. However, for whatever reason, when I navigate to futon remotely, it doesn't resolve. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Probably belongs on ServerFault at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Did you restart CouchDB after changing `bind_address`? Is there a firewall?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to mention that. Yes, I did kill and restart it. It's an Amazon EC2 instance, so I'm not sure if there's a firewall or not.

Comment: Well, if it's listening on the socket according to `netstat`, there must be something outside CouchDB blocking access (assuming the error you get is "Connection refused").

Comment: When I try to send a curl request to the database I receive "Couldn't connect to host at..."

Comment: Ahh, yes, you mentioned something about "resolve". Is it possible you're connecting to a hostname which is resolved to a different IP than what you had in mind?

Comment: When I go to just the ip, i.e. port 80, it connects just fine. When I SSH to the server and curl the couchdb instance locally, `curl localhost:5984`, I receive what I expect.

Comment: Hi Willem -- did you sort this out? I'm experiencing the very same problem. I also have my security group set with all ports open.

Comment: I upgraded my couchdb from 1.6 to 2.2 and it created a local.ini at /opt/couchdb/etc where I need to change bing_address. See if you had a similar type where the couchdb local.ini file is in different location